# Python right click on table's header

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate the download of some data from a table, to do so I need to right click on the header's table => select "Export" => and click on "Excel".

Looking to the code with the Inspect I have

```html
<div class="list_message_row"><div id="output_messages" class="outputmsg_container outputmsg_hide"><button type="button" aria-label="Close Messages" id="close-messages-btn" class="btn btn-icon close icon-cross" onclick="GlideUI.get().onCloseMessagesButtonClick(this); return false;"></button><div class="outputmsg_div" aria-live="polite" role="region" data-server-messages="false"></div></div><script>addRenderEvent(function() {CustomEvent.fire('glide_optics_inspect_update_watchfield', '');});

            var accessibilityEnabled = Boolean(false);
            if (accessibilityEnabled) {
                $j(function() {
                    $j('#output_messages .btn.btn-icon.close').focus();
                });
            }</script></div>
```

So, I tried

```py
elem = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "column_head list_hdrcell table-col-header")
```

but I get the error:

Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".column_head list_hdrcell table-col-header"}
(Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.64)

Someone can help me with this?

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url_incidents)

elem_user = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "UserName")
elem_user.clear()
elem_user.send_keys(usr)

elem_pwd = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Password")
elem_pwd.clear()
elem_pwd.send_keys(pwd)

elem_pwd.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

elems = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "column_head list_hdrcell table-col-header")
```

Comment: The element could be part of an iframe which is why it throws exception but its hard to tell without checking more html code

Comment: @AbhayChaudhary you were right, it is inside an iframe. Now it's working. Thanks